# How Sort A List<string> By A Part Of That String Desc

Tags: c#, string, list, sorting

i have a list like this :

```
List<string> list_lines = new List<string>();
list_lines.add("name1__pass1__com__14__55");
list_lines.add("name2__pass2__com__14__5445");
list_lines.add("name3__pass3__com__14__456456");
list_lines.add("name4__pass4__com__14__1357");
list_lines.add("name5__pass5__com__14__20000");
list_lines.add("name6__pass6__com__14__25");
list_lines.add("name7__pass7__com__14__12");
```

and more...

as you see there is a separator here -> "__" in every string in that list.
mean :

```
string[] Separator = new string[] { "__" };   

foreach(string s in list_lines)
{
    string[] line_ar = s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
    int Num  = int.parse(line_ar[4]);
}
```

i want to sort that list by Num parts of that list.
i test some methods using StackOverflow, but there was a bug in them for a big list.

would be really appreciate to help me for soting it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Asc:

```
list_lines = list_lines.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[4])).ToList();
```

Desc:

```
list_lines = list_lines.OrderByDescending(s => int.Parse(s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[4])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var myList = list_lines.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Split(new string[] {"__"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[4])).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think he wont to order by amount of splited items. I think he wants to order by the last number in the items.

Comment: That's ordering by the number of elements each string is split into, which isn't what is being asked for (note the `Num` in the split example).

Comment: I understood that as soon as I posted ;). Repost.

Answer (score 2):

If the number always starts after the last underscore character, then this should work:

```
var sortedList = list_lines
    .OrderByDescending(l => int.Parse(l.Substring(l.LastIndexOf("_") + 1)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you using Substring instead of split? Is it faster?

Comment: @Diego: I haven't measured, but I prefer it. Split will create an array of 5 strings for each line, whereas Substring will just return the number-part as a string.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But if the separator changes will have to change this code (unless you replace `+ 1` with `+ separator.Length - 1`). Also if some "fields" are added after the number this will change to... I'm not sure how useful it is in this particular case, but will have it in mind!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers create a **new** list which is sorted the way you want. If instead you want the **same** list to be sorted, maybe try something like this:

```
Func<string, int> getNum = str => int.Parse(str.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[4]);
list_lines.Sort((x, y) => getNum(x).CompareTo(getNum(y)));
```

This uses [an overload of `List<>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx). If you want descending order, swap `x` and `y` in the `Comparison<>` lambda body.

If your list is *very* long, this is faster (uses Quick Sort) and doesn't require the memory of a new copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of lambda expression in LINQ functions like `OrderBy`

```
string[] Separator = new string[] { "__" };
var sortedList = list_lines
    .OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Split(Separator, StringSplitOptions.None)[4]))
    .ToList();
```

As an unrelated side note, please use correct C# naming conventions so your code is easier to read and is unified with existing C# code-base. E.g. not beginning local variable names with capital letter (`Separator` -> `separator`) and using lower camel case (Pascal case) in case it contains more words (`list_lines` -> `listLines`)

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for answering a related question here:

```
Sat 2020-03-21 06:03:31.129: 03: [100001] Player 1
Sat 2020-03-21 06:03:33.119: 02: [620524] Player 22
```

*I would like to first sort the list by: 1) The number within the two [] 2) The date up until the : nn:*

Here's one way (of many ways) to do it:

```
void Main()
{
    var originalList = new List<string>
    {
        @"Sat 2020-03-21 06:03:31.129: 03: [100001] Player 1",
        @"Sat 2020-03-21 06:03:33.119: 02: [620524] Player 22",
    };
    var sortableList = originalList.Select(x => splitTheLine(x));
    var result = sortableList.OrderBy(x => x.numberPart).ThenBy(x => x.datePart).Select(x => x.wholeString);
}

(DateTime datePart, int numberPart, string wholeString) splitTheLine(string x)
{
    string[] separator = { "[", "]", ": " };
    var result = x.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
    return (DateTime.Parse(result[0]), int.Parse(result[3]), x );
}
```

I define a method `splitTheLine` to extract the *date* and *number* parts along with the original string. It returns a tuple. Then I use the method with the `select` operator of LINQ to retrieve a list with three "columns". Again with LINQ, using the `OrderBy`and `ThenBy`operators I sort the list. Finally I `select`only the originial string for the result.

This solution can be shortened a lot - but at the cost of readability, as usual.